C++ Templates, Linker error and design patterns
Please note:  This code may seem excessively complicated or raise further questions about how the Convert functions are going to do but I am intentionally only showing a very minimal example and the number of types and complexity of what I'm trying to do does warrant something of this nature.   I also am aware that c++ does not support runtime reflection which might be the next obvious comment.
Essentially, I'm trying to implement a TypeConverter that has a number of member functions that allow it to return the result of converting from one type to another.   The TypeConverter itself declares and implements the concrete functions required but the implementation of each function could use a different helper such as StructConverter.   The helpers themselves need to access TypeConverter to help convert any complex types that they intern hold as members/children.   The StructConverter itself is a template so that can be generic although some parts will need specific implementation.
However, I keep getting a linker error:
error: member access into incomplete type 'TypeConverter'
a = tc.Convert(b,tc);
^
Originally I thought a forward class declaration would be all that was required but apparently not and I've been unable to figure out if what I'm trying to do is not possible (although to me it seems conceptually fine) or if I just haven't found the appropriate c++ construct.
Many thanks in advance for any help in either getting this to build or suggestion of a pattern not too dissimilar approach that might help noting that using a template for StructConverter or similar is somewhat key to my design/desired outcome.
#include <string>

struct StructTypeA{
    int time;
    std::string source;
};

struct StructTypeB{
    int time;
    std::string source;
};

class TypeConverter;
  
template <typename A, typename B>
class StructConverter   
{
public:
    StructConverter(){;}
    A Convert(B b, TypeConverter &tc)
    {
        A a;
        a.source = b.source;
        a.time = b.time;
        // a.SomeMoreComplexType = tc.Convert(b.ComplexType);
        a = tc.Convert(b, tc); // this would be recursive but illustrates the intent and produces linker error.
        return a;
    }
};

class TypeConverter
{
  private:
    StructConverter<StructTypeA, StructTypeB> sconverter;

  public:
  StructTypeA Convert(StructTypeB b, TypeConverter &tc)
  {
    return sconverter.Convert(b, tc);
  }
};

int main()
{
        TypeConverter tc;
        StructTypeB b;
        b.source = "somewhere";
        b.time = 5;
        StructTypeA a = tc.Convert(b, tc);

        return 0;
}


You've declared a default constructor for StructConverter but haven't provided a definition.

Where is the implementation of StructConverter::StructConverter() ?

Thankyou, sorry, I've edited the sample to fix that and it also bought the real issue into focus - linker error has been updated as well.

The main problem is that here both of your classes depend on each other and more importantly one of them is actually a class template. Generally  we solve the problem by separating the implementation and declaration into source and header file but here since one of them is a class template, it's member function can't easily be separated into a source file. This seems more like a design problem to me. You could change  the design of your program so that they(the said classes/templates) don't depend on each other.

@user12002570 - yes I agree that its a dependency issue.   My primary code does have the header and source files separated.   You're comment "template member function can't easily be separated into source file" may be the knob of the I'd like to know for certain as ultimately the templated class is compiled to a specific implementation type and TypeConverter has a forward class declaration.   If the template was removed rom it there would be cases where a perfectly fine design pattern.  As noted at the top, the design is due to factors not in the post.

@jb007 Yeah, if one of the class template was a simple class(not a template), the fix was easy. But here one of them is a template and so the fix is hard. You can ofcourse still do it by using explicit template instantiations if you know the types for which the class template would be instantiated but that is generally not recommended.

You've declared a default constructor, StructConverter(), but did not define it anywhere. That's all.
Try replacing:
// ... snip ...
public:
    StructConverter();
    A Convert(B b, TypeConverter &tc)
// ... snip ...

with:
// ... snip ...
public:
    A Convert(B b, TypeConverter &tc)
// ... snip ...

(letting the compiler use a default constructor), and that will compile and link.
Having said that - this seems like rather poor design. Your "struct converter" and "type converters" don't have any business being class; they're really just functions. Remember that freestanding functions can be templated as well.

Thanks, the constructor issue was an oversight in my sample which I've now fixed so the sample better reflects my problem.   Your point about templated freestanding fuctions bares some thought; I do need StructConverter to be a class due to other implementation details but I will consider if I can make TypeConverter free floating functions.
